# Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MainPage.myWebView'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, static, public

I have a `HybridWebView` named `myWebView` declared using XAML in a **Page** called `MainPage`. The `HybridWebView` is made public using the following XAML attribute: `x:FieldModifier="public"`.

I'm trying to access `myWebView` from another **Page** in order to inject Javascript code. This has as a result the error of the title.

What's the solution?

Comment: instead of *describing* your code, it is much more helpful to actually *post* the relevant code.  And note that trying to access an element on a page from another page is generally a very poor design

Comment: Sure, what I describe though is pretty simple. I don't think that adding the code would make things more clear in this case. Anyway, what I'm trying to do is to update the WebView immediately when the settings get changed and settings are on a seperate Page. Is there another way to do it? For example is there an event raised that I can detect from `MainPage`? If yes, then there would be no reason to access the WebView from another class.

Comment: using `MessagingCenter` is typically a good way to communicate between disconnected pages/classes

Comment: the error message is clearly telling you that you do not have a reference to an instance of `MainPage` - you appear to be trying to use the type instead of an instance.  If you actually posted the code that would be clearer

Comment: @Jason Just gave a try to messaging. It worked perfectly! Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: *"what I describe though is pretty simple. "* Even so, please ALWAYS include code. ALSO describing in natural language is good; that makes it clear what you are emphasizing, but without code, what you think is unambiguous and clear, might be mis-interpreted. And takes more effort to read, because anyone reading may not have been recently working with those exact details.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to access myWebView from another Page in order to inject Javascript code. This has as a result the error of the title.
>
> What's the solution?

So I am **guessing**, as there is no code at all and a few Infos:

- custom renderers should be in place for iOS/droid **IF** you render a [View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.view?view=xamarin-forms)
- load the page first / instantiate the page // might be the best guess according to the error message ;)
- and afterward, the java-stuff is injected
- references to UIWebView or any classes that make use of UIWebView must be removed as they are deprecated.

But it could be way other stuff - may your code lead us the way :)

Comment: Never mind.. I followed @Jason's advice and used the `MessagingCenter`. It worked just as I wished!